# React scroll nav using useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am trying to make a one page app where you click the link and it scrolls down to the section corresponding to the menu item. I have spent days researching for a fix that suits my criteria and unfortunately, I am having very little luck.

My criteria is as follows:

- No external dependencies
- Must have the url in the address bar (to allow direct links to the particular section)
- Must not be hacky (i.e Injecting the URL into the address bar)
- Must be as simple as possible

I hope that isn't asking for too much.

You can have a play around with my CodeSandbox [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-meadow-fv32v?file=/src/App.tsx). Forks are appreciated!

Comment: Ok. So. First issue I discovered is that navlink cannot both function and run an onClick. Work arounds 1. Add a subcomponent with an onclick, 2. Handle all Navlink things in onclick (seems like too much). Second issue is using ref in functional components. I'm looking into that now. I think there is a hook for that. I'll post an answer and a fork when I find it.

Comment: Ok. You were using the ref hook. But there is a scoping issue. Using it at the header level does little for you in the other levels. Let me play around with this some more. I think Ive almost got it.

Comment: I've got to stop for now. https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-microservice-3bqml?file=/src/App.tsx should be the link to onclick working. You've got to play with ref forwarding to get the ref where you need it. https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap each section with the `forwardRef` HOC. Create and set a `ref` for each section, and pass the refs to the header component so it can call the `scrollIntoView` function on them.

*edit* Added an effect to look at the location and trigger scrolling.

```
const Header = ({ refs }) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("location", location.pathname);
    switch (location.pathname) {
      case "/about":
        scrollSmoothHandler(refs.aboutRef);
        break;
      case "/contact":
        scrollSmoothHandler(refs.contactRef);
        break;
      case "/hero":
        scrollSmoothHandler(refs.heroRef);
        break;

      default:
      // ignore
    }
  }, [location, refs]);

  const scrollSmoothHandler = ref => {
    console.log("Triggered.");
    ref.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <NavLink to="/hero" activeClassName="selected">
        Hero
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/about" activeClassName="selected">
        About
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/contact" activeClassName="selected">
        Contact
      </NavLink>
    </>
  );
};

const Hero = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <section ref={ref}>
      <h1>Hero Section</h1>
    </section>
  );
});

const About = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <section ref={ref}>
      <h1>About Section</h1>
    </section>
  );
});

const Contact = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <section ref={ref}>
      <h1>Contact Section</h1>
    </section>
  );
});

function App() {
  const heroRef = useRef(null);
  const aboutRef = useRef(null);
  const contactRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HashRouter>
        <Header refs={{ aboutRef, contactRef, heroRef }} />
        <Hero ref={heroRef} />
        <About ref={aboutRef} />
        <Contact ref={contactRef} />
      </HashRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit forwardRef and scrollIntoView]

Comment: Thank you! That does work, however, it doesn't quite match the criteria. Do you know how to adjust the code so if I typed `/contact` in the address bar it would scroll down to the contact section?

Comment: @Julian Added an effect to trigger scrolling view when location changes. No need for onclick now.

Comment: what if I wanted to convert the components to TypeScript? For example: `interface IAbout {
  ref: any
}

const About: React.FC<IAbout> = forwardRef((ref) => {
  return (
    <section ref={ref}>
      <h1>About Section</h1>
    </section>
  );
});` I get an error when I try this.

Comment: @Julian Unfortunately I'm not versed in typescript. A quick google search yielded this: https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/react-refs-with-typescript-a32d56c4d315 With it I was able to remove the warnings/errors in all the components but the Header.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will give it another shot. Also I have tried to move the refs out of the `App()` but I am getting ref.current is null. Any ideas? Can this even be done?

Comment: I am on my phone so code sandbox won't let me do much so here is a pastebin of what I have done to it: https://pastebin.com/GpjRbd8N

Comment: @Julian It could possibly be done as they really only need to be defined *in some* common ancestor. In the demo `App` just happens to be the *closest* (and only) common ancestor. IMO it makes sense to define them in the component holding the router/routes as *that component* is the one likely to have the best picture of the routes or elements that need to be scrolled to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211846/discussion-between-julian-and-drew-reese).